# Delete underscores from end phrase

Tags: bash, sed

I have table names that I'd like to rename :
Here some examples :

```
AB_DC_JDZOJZD_HST_2090
AB_DC_JDZODSJOJZD_HIST_2500
AB_DC_JDZ_JJKOJZD_HIT_2050
```

But I want :

```
AB_DC_JDZOJZD
AB_DC_JDZODSJOJZD
AB_DC_JDZ_JJKOJZD
```

My question is :
How to remove  from the end of the word ?

Comment: What's the logic underlying? Up to `_H`? Up to the penultimate underscore?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you want to remove the last two *fields* delimited by `_`, you could say:

```
sed -r 's/(_[^_]*){2}$//' filename
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
AB_DC_JDZOJZD
AB_DC_JDZODSJOJZD
AB_DC_JDZ_JJKOJZD
```

---

For fun, you could also use `rev` and `cut` to produce the same output:

```
rev filename | cut -d_ --complement -f1,2 | rev
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried  sed 's/_[a-zA-Z0-9]*_[a-zA-Z0-9]*$//, which is better ?

Comment: @user2269756 It depends on you.  The version you've suggested would not match inputs like: `AB_DC_JDZOJZD_HS:T_2090`

Answer (score 1):

Just use parameter expansion in the shell:

```
while read word; do echo "${word%_*_*}"; done <<END
AB_DC_JDZOJZD_HST_2090
AB_DC_JDZODSJOJZD_HIST_2500
AB_DC_JDZ_JJKOJZD_HIT_2050
END
```

```
AB_DC_JDZOJZD
AB_DC_JDZODSJOJZD
AB_DC_JDZ_JJKOJZD
```

Comment: Work but very heavy in resource compare to a awk or sed if input is a bit long. Still give a 1Up

Comment: I would argue with "resource heavy" -- after all you're not spawning any other processes. I would concede slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`

```
awk -F_ '{NF-=2}8' OFS="_" file
AB_DC_JDZOJZD
AB_DC_JDZODSJOJZD
AB_DC_JDZ_JJKOJZD
```

This removes two last field using `_` as separator.